# Ocaml cast string to list of tuples

Tags: casting, tuples, ocaml

I have the file "example.dat" with text `"[(1,2); (3,4); (5,6)]"`. I need to get list of tuples from it. I know, how I can get it from list of ints.

```
# let f line = List.map int_of_string line;;
# open Printf
      let file = "example.dat"  
      let () =
      let ic = open_in file in
        try 
          let line = input_line ic in        
  f line;
  flush stdout;
        close_in ic
        with e ->
        close_in_noerr ic;
        raise e;;
```

How I must to change my functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let parse_array_string array_string =
  let open Genlex in
  let open Stream in
  let lexer = make_lexer ["["; "("; ","; ")"; ";"; "]";] in
  let stream = lexer (of_string array_string) in
  let fail () = failwith "Malformed string" in
  let parse_tuple acc = 
    match next stream with
    | Int first -> ( 
        match next stream with
        | Kwd "," -> ( 
            match next stream with
            | Int second -> ( 
                match next stream with
                | Kwd ")" -> (first, second) :: acc
                | _ -> fail () 
              )
            | _ -> fail () 
          )
        | _ -> fail () 
      )
    | _ -> fail ()
    in
    let rec parse_array acc =
      match next stream with
      | Kwd "(" -> parse_array (parse_tuple acc)
      | Kwd ";" -> parse_array acc
      | Kwd "]" -> acc
      | _ -> fail ()
    in
    try
      match next stream with
      | Kwd "[" -> List.rev (parse_array [])
      | _ -> fail ()
    with Stream.Failure -> fail ();;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of strings that represent ints, your function `f` returns a list of ints. It doesn't return a list of tuples.

You don't say whether you want to verify that the input has some kind of proper form. If you want to verify that it has the form of (say) a list of type `(int * int) list` in OCaml, this is a parsing problem that would take some work.

If you just want to extract the parts of the input line that look like ints, you can use regular expression processing from the `Str` module:

```
# let re = Str.regexp "[^0-9]+" in
  Str.split re "[(1,2); (37,4); (5,6)]";;
- : string list = ["1"; "2"; "37"; "4"; "5"; "6"]
```

Then you can rewrite your function `f` to collect up each pair of ints into a tuple. I don't see a good way to use `List.map` for this. You might have to write your own recursive function or use `List.fold_left`.

**Update**

I will write you a function that changes a list of values into a list of pairs. I hope this isn't for a school assignment, in which case you should be figuring this out for yourself.

```
let rec mkpairs l =
    match l with
    | [] | [_] -> []
    | a :: b :: rest -> (a, b) :: mkpairs rest
```

As you can see, this function silently discards the last element of the list if the list has an odd number of elements.

This function is not tail recursive. So that's something you could think about improving.

Comment: I need to get list of ints pairs for using in next functions:
```
# let binomial (n, p) =
  let binom n p =
      if p < 0 || n < 0 || p > n then 0
      else (
        let a = ref 1 in
        for i = 1 to p  do
            a := !a * (n + 1 - i) / i
        done;
        !a
      )
  and comp = n - p
  in if (comp < p) then
    binom n comp
  else
    binom n p;;

let comb l = List.map binomial l;;
```

Comment: (I added a function for making a list into a list of pairs.)